# SQL Query for Product table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I ask this question for small model of my main table.

I have a table `Product` and I want a result table like this from a SQL query:

```
Color     |  existing Color count  |  existing sizes from this color
----------+------------------------+--------------------------------
red       |             20         |  3
black     |             12         |  4
```

`Product` table has `[Id, Name, Color, Size, Price]` columns.

I wrote this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    Color, 
    COUNT(Color) AS "numbers", 
    COUNT(Size) AS "sizes" 
FROM
    [Production].[Product] 
GROUP BY
    Color, Size;
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. See [ask] for more information. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @rsjaffe I added my tried code.

Comment: What's the result of your query? Are you receiving an error or just an undesired result?

Comment: @versvs I receive the undesired result.

Comment: Provide the input data sample ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Yes I did it, I use Microsoft sample databases, and I have the undesired result now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select color,count(color),count(distinct size) from table 
 group by color;
```

> Is this what you want ?

Comment: It is worked but didn't count ```NULL``` as a size type. I want to count that rows hasn't any size value. is it possible?